# Running a React Dockerfile gives me an error in ubuntu 18

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./app/
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.0.1 -g --silent

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

docker-compose

```
webapp:
    container_name: webapp
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: app/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

[image]

I am trying to build a react project in docker. I can't understand why it can't find index.html? Should it work without nginx?

Comment: Where is the file in your local source tree?  What does `npm run start` actually do?  Have you looked at the contents of the built image to see if they match what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

So it worked

docker-compose

```
  webapp:
    container_name: webapp
    build:
      context: ../zhyvedotnet.auctionthings.webapp
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 4200:80
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10-alpine as builder
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install && mkdir /react-ui && mv ./node_modules ./react-ui
WORKDIR /react-ui
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
COPY --from=builder /react-ui/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 3000 80
ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

nginx.conf

```
worker_processes 4;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        location /appui {
            try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
    }
}
```